# Why can't I connect to the SQL Server instance on my local machine?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have just installed SQL Server 2016 (Developer Edition) database engine on my dev machine (Windows 10).

When installing I named the instance `CUBE`, with Windows authentication using the current (only) user's credentials.

I can see the instance running in Services:

[image: Services]

When I try to login using SQL Management Studio I get the following error:

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible...`

**Things I've tried:**

- Checked the server is running (it is)
- Opened firewall port 1433 (no difference)
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration I've enabled **Named Pipes** and **TCP/IP**

I can't see what I'm doing wrong - can anyone help?

Comment: Check below URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: I've updated my post. The server is running and I've tried opening a firewall port (even though shouldn't have to since it's not a remote instance).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the `MSSQLSERVER` service is running, you can check the following article from microsoft on how to manipulate the `MSSQLSERVER Service`.

[Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, Restart the Database Engine, SQL Server Agent, or SQL Server Browser Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx)

finally, take a look to the following post it might help you:

[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: Thanks for this, why would I need the MSSQLSERVER default instance if I've installed a named instance?

Comment: you would not, but i referred to your instance as the default just to be generic in the answer. good luck!